# Verify Signature of SAML Response

Tags: java, digital-signature, saml, public-key-encryption, shibboleth

I'm trying to follow the following spec to verify the signature of the SAML response: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-PKCS1

Here is my workflow: I get the SAML Response. I get rid of the signature envelope, I canonicalize it, I check the digest and then I check the signature. I was able to successfully calculate SHA1 digest of the transformed SAML response and verify it. However, RSA-SHA1 signature checking still eludes me.

SAML Response included signature method algorithm: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1

I have this method to check the signature:

```
public static boolean verifySignature(String signatureType, PublicKey publicKey, byte[] contentBytes, byte[] sigBytes) {
    try {
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(signatureType);
        sig.initVerify(publicKey);
        sig.update(contentBytes);
        return sig.verify(sigBytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.log(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I do something like this to call it:

```
String publicKeyStr =  "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";
PublicKey publicKey = Security.getPublicKey(publicKeyStr); // uses Certificate class
String sig = "QfAcRJM2P65JucyBpqn6j48/zd1oSLPBJ0lYI1grH5/xenwBEh0D4Eh0S1J3535OUmldpW7D+G7DW6eAT5N8TdoqUvMXuIAUpFHHDR45KZykPXJPUtli+z2rwlCCHypZWnniT/wrcQYdpp1zzNJBBtKdkaqQg0NMktPSQ/0ti+ruMI3qwfTaL9kDQ3Zyi/a2J3RCAPA0RfviLnDLlid0PthiV1NEbs0AvnguDi57fWXAILk0L1Cx20sliQckxlFQ9u4OaHeMscXdjh3SfESkM9m0Y9PppisZWTrCYzGmvDwsZTCBPD3f/ZFIit+Smgh2fi1u8/gZq0yizPyacR3Y/A==";
String newXMLToOperateOn = "<saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ID="_420cc1a25a3890bd5df1f4c04bd7e986" ...";

boolean sign = Security.verifySignature("SHA1withRSA", pk, newXMLToOperateOn.getBytes(), Util.base64DecodeAsBytes(sig));
// SIGN IS FALSE!!!!
```

`newXMLToOperateOn` is the correct canonicalized string XML of the SAMLResponse. This is what I use to generate the correct SHA1 digest. Security.verify() works correctly since I use to for OpenID SSO checking and that works.

**I also tried to substitute the data to check instead of the entire XML to the bytes of the SHA1 digest, but didn't work either.** E.G. `verify(algo, pk, sha1Digest.getBytes(), sig.getBytes()`.

***Can someone tell me if there is something that I'm doing horribly wrong when checking the signature?*** The spec linked above tells me the signing method does this:

```
   CRYPT (PAD (ASN.1 (OID, DIGEST (data))))
```

Which doesn't help me a ton when I'm verifying the signature. I cannot recreate the signature since I can't find what private key they use in their examples.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to verify the 'SignedInfo' portion of the XML